# Query SQL Database and Store Results in a Variable VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to query a SQL DB using a textbox field and retreive a column from the DB and store it in a variable so I can use it in other places within my site.  My web form requires the user to enter a few items such as name and zip code.

My database has 3 columns; email address, zip code, and id.  I need the input form to query the database and return the "email address" that matches the user's inputted "zip code"

I understand the SQL SELECT statement and the connection string is correct.  My queries are working, I just can't seem to figure out how to get the returned "email address" to store in a variable. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim strconnection As String, strSQL As String, strZipCheck As String
    Dim objconnection As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim objcmd As OleDbCommand = Nothing
    Dim RREmail As String = Nothing
    Dim zipQuery As String = zipCodeBox.Text
    'connection string
    strconnection = "provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXX;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXXXXXX;"

    objconnection = New OleDbConnection(strconnection)
    objconnection.ConnectionString = strconnection


    'opens connection to database
    objconnection.Open()
    strSQL = "SELECT [EMAIL ADDRESS] FROM ZIPCODEDATA WHERE [ZIP CODE] = @ZIP CODE "
    objcmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, objconnection)

    RREmail = CType(objcmd.ExecuteScalar(), String)
    lblRREmail.Text = RREmail
    objconnection.Close()
```

Comment: where are you specifying the zip code parameter?

Comment: As Goose has implied, you're going to have to call `objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZIP", zipQuery)` or the like to set your zip code parameter.  With that, it looks like your code already does what you want.  Mind you what if the user enters an invalid zip code?  That query will still retrieve NULL and you're not allowing for that.

Comment: Moreover, your parameter name cannot have a space in it, if you wish @zip_code to be your parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

While the other comments do point out particular deficiencies with your syntax, I would like to address the question of storing a variable and take it a bit further. I generally do not use parameterized connections  unless I am calling stored procedures and need an output parameter.  Instead, here is what I often do to create a database connection and get my results.

First I create a public class called dbConn so I dont have to write it out a million times.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class dbConn
    Public Property strSQL As String
    Private objConn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = _
            New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(local)\dev;Initial Catalog=testDataBase;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security = true;")
    Public Function getDt() As DataTable
        Dim Conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim da As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Try
            objConn.Open()
            da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, objConn)
            da.Fill(dt)
            da = Nothing
            objConn.Close()
            objConn = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            objConn.Close()
            objConn = Nothing
        End Try
        Return dt
    End Function
End Class
```

Then from another class (lets assume its form1) I call up that function to get a datatable returned to me. In this case I select TOP 1 to save your sanity in case by chance there is more than one email address per zip code.

```
Public sub getdata() 

    Dim strEmailAddress As String = Nothing

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New dbConn
    da.strSQL = " select top 1 [email address] from [zipcode] " _
            & " where [zip code] = '" & strZipCode & "'" _
            & " order by [email address] asc"
    dt = da.getDt
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Not IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString) Then
            strEmailAddress = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

From there you can use strEmailAddress within the sub after it is set, or you can move the string declaration outside of the sub as a public string declaration to use it elsewhere, or you can create other classes like an email class with a public property for strEmailAddress to pass it off to, etc.

I hope something in there helps you understand how to deal with your problem.

Comment: Also, on a side note, I would recommend avoiding the use of spaces in your column names when you create a table because its easier to deal with all around.

Comment: I know this was posted over a year ago but I'd also like to point out that any cleanup code (like `objConn.Close`) should go in a `Finally` block. If an exception is thrown before the line to close the SQL connection, it will not close it. Putting it in `Finally` will allow it to run the close line even if an exception is thrown.